# CLion does not properly reload the CMake project

Tags: clion

I am using CLion on Linux:

```
CLion 2016.1.3
Build #CL-145.1617, built on June 7, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b198 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

to build a shared library, but somehow it refuses to reload the generated cmake project when I use the *Reload CMake Project* button from **Tools->CMake** menu.

When I do a complete reset with **Tools->CMake->Reset Cache and Reload Project** the generated cmake files are removed from the `/home/username/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/my_project-c36f8f47/c36f8f47` folder, but no new files are generated.

The only way to update the project now is to restart the IDE. Somehow it can generate the files when the IDE starts, but I don't know why.

Does anyone have an idea on why this problem occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked the problem down to the *configure_file* command of cmake. When I removed the call to this command from my project the problem did not occur.  However, when I tried to reproduce the issue in a minimal project, it also did not occur.

So my problem was solved by just avoiding the use of *configure_file*, but I could not confirm that the command itself was actually responsible. Some strange behavior indeed.